# How to update value of computed observable

Tags: knockout.js

I have this in the view model:

```
self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

    self.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        var selectedItem = ko.unwrap(self.selectedItem);
        if (selectedItem) {
            return ko.unwrap(selectedItem.FullName);
        }
    });

self.editStatus = function(item) {
        self.selectedItem = item;
        if (self.selectedItem === null) {
            alert("No items selected");
        }
        $('#editStatus').modal('show');

    }
```

Then I have a table with a column which is a link:

```
<td data-bind="if: CanEditPostCloseStatus"><a data-bind="text: OrderPostCloseStatusName, click: $parent.editStatus"></a></td>
```

I then have a bootstrap modal which when activated should show the fullName.

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <p data-bind="text: fullName" ></p>
</div>
```

The issue is that the modal always shows up with an empty fullName.

How do I tell Knockout to update the binding when the selectedItem changes so that the fullName is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified.  First lets fix a bug:  `self.selectedItem` is an observable so to update it we need to call it like a function.

```
self.editStatus = function(item) {
    self.selectedItem(item);  // fixed this assignment
    if (!self.selectedItem()) { // fixed reading this value
        alert("No items selected");
    }
    $('#editStatus').modal('show');

}
```

Now in the modal, we can use knockout's [with binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html)

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedItem" class="modal-body">
        <p data-bind="text: fullName" ></p>
</div>
```